# Copy view into another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server atabases A and B and want to **copy a view from database A to database B using SQL only**. B is used as history db, all the tables from A are also in B.

**The existent views from A should be copied (re-created) into B in a way that they point to data in B.**

The task is easy to solve using SQL Management Studio ([e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913685/how-to-copy-views-from-one-database-to-another-database)), but I need to be able to copy these views using my own program.

Where is the necessary information stored to generate the CREATE VIEW statements?

Could SELECT INTO or INSERT INTO provide a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
USE DatabaseA;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ViewName');

EXEC DatabaseB..sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you want to create *all* views, then:

```
USE DatabaseA;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + m.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS s
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON s.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.type_desc = 'VIEW';

EXEC DatabaseB..sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you want this to be repeatable, you need to also drop each view first, if it already exists in the destination database. So for example:

```
USE DatabaseA;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'IF OBJECT_ID('''
    + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ''') IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN
        DROP VIEW ' 
        + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]))
        + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ';
      END'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + s.definition
FROM sys.sql_modules AS s
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON s.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.type_desc = 'VIEW';

EXEC DatabaseB..sp_executesql @sql;
```

Now keep in mind that this will not create indexes if any of these are indexed views, it also doesn't validate that the view can actually be created in the other database (unless you are positive that all the dependent objects are identical between the two databases), and doesn't ensure the order of creation (in the case where ViewA calls ViewB, it may not create them in the correct order). Much better to use a schema comparison tool to automate this for you. I wrote about this here:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: Thank you very much. You meant **s.definition** instead of m.definition, right?

Comment: Wow, you're really really fast. Thanks again :)

Comment: I stopped using Dells and Windows years ago. I think that affords me to be a little quicker. :-)

Comment: I get an error using your last snippet. The generated code looks absolutely correct, but it doesn't execute using EXEC. But it executes if I copy paste the generated code. Could the problem result from the line breaks (I haven't stopped using Windows yet)?

Comment: Using EXEC or using EXEC DatabaseB..sp_executesql? That latter part is important. Also what does "doesn't execute" mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10797/discussion-between-a1337q-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: The origin of the Problem is the `GO`, which is only used to separate batches in SSMS. How could I separate the batches with the `IF`'s and the `CREATE VIEW`'s?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the chat invitation. If you are doing this in application code, you will need to split the code by GO and send each portion of the code as a separate batch from the application. Or better yet, just wrap the code in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure. The GO commands won't be passed back and forth between the app and the database, so this should work fine.

Comment: Okay, it's true, I can use this well in application code, which is my intention. Another problem just occurred: When I use `PRINT @sql` to have a look at the generated code, it's not complete, meaning it stops in the middle of a `CREATE VIEW`-statement. Is the size of @sql limited? Or could it only be a problem with `PRINT` in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Bertrand's answer is awesome, as always.  But for completeness, Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index-b) will do this quite nicely and [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) provides functionality, like the scripter class, that make this relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks Timothy. The blog post I point to talks about SQL Compare and several alternatives (the thrust of the post is that these tools are already going to be much more functional and bug-free than any script you will whip up yourself or procure from some smart-alec on StackOverflow). :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works in at least SQL2005 and beyond, not sure about earlier versions.

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('<schema_name.object_name>')
```

You can't use SELECT INTO or INSERT INTO because a view isn't a table and doesn't hold any data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this from you destination database (databaseB):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @sql = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID)
FROM    [databaseA].sys.views
WHERE   name = 'View_1'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Careful, you want to use NVARCHAR(MAX) there. And you should probably use EXEC sp_executesql, not EXEC. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx and finally you should also reference the schema of the view to be safe https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Comment: I'm not sold on using EXEC over SP_EXECUTESQL in this case since he wouldn't care about reusing the plan or SQL injection.  And NVARCHAR would have a limit of 8000 characters where NVARCHAR would limit at 4000.  However, if OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) returns an NVARCHAR, then I agree.

Comment: OBJECT_DEFINITION does return an NVARCHAR, and since it's MAX it's not limited to 4000 or 8000 characters at all. And why use EXEC in some cases when you should use sp_executesql in others? Consistency leads to best practices, needing to know when to use one over the other leads to neither. IMHO.

Comment: Changed to NVARCHAR.  Since it doesn't matter if you use EXEC or SP_EXECUTESQL in this specific case, I'll leave it.

Comment: Wasn't trying to correct your answer, just making sure other readers are aware of the issues. FWIW I don't use EXEC in any sample code because it *implies* that it's ok to use in all cases, and even though it will work if users apply it to other scenarios, it is more dangerous and prone to the issues I brought up in my post.