# SQL Copy from Production to Dev Environments

Tags: sql, sql-server, production-environment, dev-to-production

I want to be able to copy all data within a production environment to a dev environment on a weekly basis so that when I am developing, I have updated data in my dev environment.

Database Names: PAth15 - Prod; DAth15-2 and

Again, I want to move all data from the prod environment to the dev, both environments are mirror images of each other in regards to structure.

Comment: Then why not just make a backup of prod and restore it in dev?

Comment: How big is the DB? I'm asking because if it is 200MB you can just backup production and attach the db to dev

Comment: What are you having problems with? Making a backup?  Restoring it?  Automating something?

Comment: I have tried the backup and restore, it doenst like it too much. I am having trouble automating the process, would rather not manually do it. the databases are small (less than 200MB) but will grow rather quickly

Comment: What db consists of? What objects? (Tables, Views, SP, TVF, etc...) What SQL server it is? Standard or Express? 2012?

Comment: Really All i want to copy is the tables and view - I am not TOO concerned with the SP's, TVF's, etc. it is standard too NOT Express

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913685/how-to-copy-views-from-one-database-to-another-database Right click on your database and say Tasks->Generate scripts. SQL Server Management Studio is able to generate the CREATE scripts for you.

Then you simple copy this script and execute it on the target server/database.