# Programmatically copy Database Views from one Database Server to another

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two Database-Servers (lets call them "outside" and "inside") and I would like to retrieve views from the "outside" server and store them on the "inside" server. The "inside" server is an MS SQL-Server, I do not know a lot about the other one, but I assume it's MS SQL, too. Now there are Views on the "outside" server that I need to map into my database-structure daily. So I want to grab the views once a day and then work with them.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913685/how-to-copy-views-from-one-database-to-another-database/1913707) but I cannot say how I could copy views programmatically. Might there be an option in MS SQL Server to copy views from another server or something like that?

Comment: If the other server is MS SQL Server just query its sys.sql_modules filtered by views, but if it's another RDBMS there will be no sql_modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use below quires to get the definition of all the view-

1) for first time to create view -

```
 select  t1.definition  , N'
 Go
 ' 
 from sys.sql_modules  t1
 join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  t2
 on object_name(t1.object_id) = t2.TABLE_NAME and TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

2) Query to Alter view on daily basis -

```
 select   replace( t1.definition , 'create view ','alter view ')  , N'
 Go
 ' 
 from sys.sql_modules  t1
 join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  t2
 on object_name(t1.object_id) = t2.TABLE_NAME and TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW
```

run above queries on your source sever take the output into text and execute it on destination server. Make sure your are taking result to text and "max char display in each column" setting of SSMS is 8000( in SSMS top menu go to Query-> Query Option ->Results->text ).

Comment: Just for me to understand the code: 

1) Gets me the views as text, selects all the views from the sys.sql_modules by joining it on all tables existing?

2) I am not really sure what this does to be honest. Can you explain this point a little bit further?

Thanks already for your answer!

Comment: sql_modules contains the definitions of all the objects like - views , SP , trigger , user defined functions etc.. To filter out views definitions we join this  with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. this table contains the list of user defined tables and views in a database.  So the last condition in the query "TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' " will make sure we are taking the definition of views only.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rahul's response:

```
select   replace( t1.definition , 'create view ','create or alter view ')  , N'
Go
' 
from sys.sql_modules  t1
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  t2
on object_name(t1.object_id) = t2.TABLE_NAME and TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

One single statement to execute irrespective of first time or subsequent runs.